# handleClientLoad function not called in Google Drive example

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying out the example given [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-client).  Specifically, the following code is giving me trouble:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var CLIENT_ID = 'xxx...';
  var SCOPES = [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
      'email',
      'profile',
    ];

  function handleClientLoad() {
    alert("Hi");
    checkAuth();
  }
```

I traced, and the file `client.js` was downloaded by my browser.  However, `handleClientLoad()` was not called.

Is the example complete and runnable or is anything else needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Callback, handleClientLoad(), is not invoking on loading of client.js library. My guess is that as soon as it loads the client library and tries to invoke the callback, callback (handleClientLoad()) is undefined. To make it working, you should put first script block,`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>`, after the end of second script block. It's working for me.

Try to run your code following way(tested and working for me),

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var CLIENT_ID = 'xxx...';
  var SCOPES = [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
      'email',
      'profile',
    ];

  function handleClientLoad() {
    alert("Hi");
    checkAuth();
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```